# Append NSString to NSURL?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring, append, nsurl

I have an NSURL, a file path, and I want to add an NSString to the end of it (the file name) how can I do this? But after this is don't I want the entire thing to be an NSURL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's as simple as:

```
    NSString *s = [aUrl.path stringByAppendingString:@"newString"];
```

Comment: If you use this, to get an NSURL in the end, you will have to do this: `[NSURL URLWithString:[aUrl.path stringByAppendingString:@"newString"]]`

Answer (score 111):

I think it's good solution:

```
NSURL *bUrl = [aUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"newString"];
```

In Swift you could do the following,

```
var bURL = aURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent( "newString" )
```

You can also state whether the URL is a directory,

```
var bURL = aURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent( "newString", isDirectory: true )
```

Comment: Note this does url encoding of the path component string

Comment: This also prepends a slash before the string.

Comment: In Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1, this is now: `appendingPathComponent(_:)`. [Docs.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1410614-appendingpathcomponent)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a file NSURL to a directory and you want to end up with a NSString containing the NSURL's path with a file name appended to it, use this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/System" isDirectory:YES];
NSString *filename = @"foo";
NSString *result = [url.path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

You can also use `URLByAppendingPathComponent` but that adds an extra step which creates an extra NSURL object that isn't needed.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/System" isDirectory:YES];
NSString *filename = @"foo";
NSURL *newURL = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
NSString *result = newURL.path;
```